# Spring WS: Add custom SOAP header

Tags: java, soap, xsd, spring-ws, payload

**What's my goal?**

I'm rather new to Spring WS, I got a WSDL (and along some XSDs, ofcourse) and i want to add some custom header elements to the SOAP response.
 I've been searching the web, tried various code pieces, but it's all without any luck... nothing seems to work properly .

**What's the problem?**

The response SOAP message has a body what spring calls a Payload and my SOAP client (SOAPUI) receives the response rather well. 
 But here it comes: how should I add new (custom) SOAP headers to the response message?

**What's the response xml expected?**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<aud:HeaderInfo xmlns:bd="http://www.myws.com/">
     <bd:ID>123</bd:ID>
     <bd:Type>text</bd:Type>
  </aud:HeaderInfo>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ne:myWS xmlns:ne="http://www.iways.com/">
     <ne:INFO>
           <ne:NAME>JOHN</ne:NAME>
           <ne:DESIGNATION>ITA</ne:DESIGNATION>
           <ne:MOBILE>9841011113</ne:MOBILE>
     </ne:INFO>
  </ne:myWS>
```

**My payload**

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "myWSRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)

public @ResponsePayload myWSResponse getInfo(@RequestPayload myWSRequest request)
{
    myWSResponse response = new myWSResponse();
    Person person = personService_i.getAccountDetails(request.getID());
    response.setPersonDetails(person);
    return response;
}
```

**Any side info?**

i use xsd which generates a load of classes based upon the XSDs I don't know how to add those custom headers to the response message,

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [endpointInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/interceptor/EndpointInterceptorAdapter.html) and do the following:

```
public final class MyEndpointInterceptorAdapter extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext_, Object endpoint_) 
throws IOException {

            WebServiceMessage _webServiceMessage = messageContext_.getResponse();
            SoapMessage _soapMessage = (SoapMessage) _webServiceMessage;

            if (_soapMessage != null) {
                SoapEnvelope _soapEnvelope = _soapMessage.getEnvelope();

                // create your qname object
                QName _myQName = ....
                // adding your quname to the header
                _soapEnvelope.getHeader().addHeaderElement(myQName );
            }
    }
}
```

and in your spring configuration file, just add the interceptor:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <ref bean="myEndpointInterceptorAdapter"/>
</sws:interceptors>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please help with MyEndpointInterceptorAdapter  how to create below header elements using qname? <aud:HeaderInfo xmlns:bd="http://www.myws.com/">
     <bd:ID>123</bd:ID>
     <bd:Type>text</bd:Type>
  </aud:HeaderInfo>